# Efficient way to display details of list item

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am working on app that is targeted to 7" or above tablets. So target platform is Android 3.x.
I am looking for an efficient approach to display details for list item when it is clicked. I have a list displayed with bunch of items. (Note: Due to the nature of the application I do not want to share ListView with other view or Fragment in this activity). When an item of list gets clicked I have to display details of that time. Details of an item take pretty much whole screen. I have couple of approach in mind:

1. Simplest one is : on List item clicked simply start an Activity that displays details of that item. But I guess it didn't seem efficient as every time item is clicked this Detail Activity is created and then destroyed.
2. Create a custom dialog for Detail of list item and hold its reference in List Activity. As soon as item is clicked show this dialog displaying contents corresponding to clicked list item. With this approach I would like Dialog to take complete screen (any suggestion appreciated).
3. Define FrameLayout in ListView with Visibility Gone (so that frame layout dont take any space in ListView screen). This frame layout act as a container for Details Fragment. As soon as list item is clicked hide ListView and make frame layout visible. With this approach I am not efficiently navigate back and forth between list view and details view.
4. Should come from an Android expert. :)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any reason why you can't take approach 1 (create an `Activity` to display the details). Even better combine 1 & 2 to create an `Activity` with a dialog theme with something like this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`...

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailsActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

Give the `Activity` a 'Close' button which when clicked, calls `finish()` to exit the `Activity`. I have several dialog-themed `Activities` in my current project and they work really well.

Comment: This is what my concern with this approach. I am creating and destroying DetailsActivity every time user clicks on List item. I would like to keep Details View (either as a Custom Dialog or Fragment or better approach?)and just change its content corresponding to List item and display it.